# Java delimiter while reading text file - regex/or not?

Tags: java, regex, delimiter, text-files, separator

I am trying to read a text file written in this form:

```
    AB523:[joe, pierre][charlie][dogs,cat]
    ZZ883:[ronald, zigomarre][pele]
```

I would like to create my structure and retrieve the information properly.

AB523 --- alone
joe,pierre ---alone
charlie ---alone
dogs,cat --- alone

I am not sure what's the best technique that should be used. I've tried StringTokenizer ...and played with regEx but I can't get it right

Do you have any solution? or suggestion

What's is the convention when writting in a text file? What are the best pratices with delimiters?

**EDIT:The textfile is also generated by me, so I have control over the overall pattern. What would be the best output pattern to reduce the amount of work when re-reading it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#split` or `Pattern#split` Method.
For example,

```
   String[] list ="AB523:[joe, pierre][charlie][dogs,cat]".split("[:\\[\\]]+");
   for(String s : list)
       System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Can you please explain me your regular expression ?

Comment: @user1023021: split the input string using any one of the delimiters(`:`,`[`,`]`) one or more times.

Answer (score 2):

I would use regular expressiones here, because it seems like less code to maintain, and your language is certainly regular. Along with a `java.util.Scanner` instance for more efficiency. Here's some code:

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ScannerTest {

private static final Pattern header = Pattern.compile("(.*):");
private static final Pattern names = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Reader reader = new StringReader(
            "AB523:[joe, pierre][charlie][dogs,cat]\n"
                    + "ZZ883:[ronald, zigomarre][pele]");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
    scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String h = scanner.findInLine(header);
        // Substring removes trailing ':'.
        System.out.println(h.substring(0, h.length() - 1));

        String n;
        while ((n = scanner.findInLine(names)) != null)
            // Substring removes '[' and ']'.
            System.out.println(n.substring(1, n.length() - 1));

        if (scanner.hasNext())
            scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
}
```

Nevertheless, I still couldn't manage to remove the substring invocations, and maybe that hides some inefficiency. My guess is that not, due to the immutability of strings, strings shouldn't be recreated for this case.

EDIT: for better performance I would also consider a handcrafted [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: I totally understand what you did there. Somehow, I'm wondering if it's the best solution. I've added a comment in my original post...to say that I also generate the textfile so I can also change the output pattern.

Comment: Then define/use XML, you'll find tons and tons of useful APIs/tools.

Answer (score 0):

Single-character delimiters are easy to split by: the String.split() function will split on a character or string.  They do exactly what a StringTokenizer does, but do it with a cleaner syntax.  That is, `String[] items = myString.split(",")` looks much cleaner than

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myString, ","); 
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    myList.add(st.nextToken();
}
```

(Use `split` in the future is what I'm saying.)

However, it looks like you're in a slightly more complicated situation, where you need to get the stuff bordered on the left by `[` and on the right by `]`.  This calls for regex, and capturing groups.  Something like `/\[(.*)\]/`

CSV (comma separated values) are common for simple tabular data, and the format is even standardized to a degree.  If you want to represent more complicated objects, then you can use JSON or SOAP.  If you're only using the storage for Java, take a look at Java's built-in serializing features.

Since you're using it locally, and probably you're saving some sort of Java object to represent it, one way would be to implement `Serializable` in whatever object is representing your data.

If you don't like that, I'd go with JSON because it looks like you're doing some sort of tree structure.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The textfile is also generated by me, so I have control over the overall pattern. What would be the best output pattern to reduce the amount of work when re-reading it ?

Comment: I would say it depends on where you're getting the data from, but if these are strictly alphabetical strings you've got, you can choose a second delimiter, like `;` (e.g. `AB523:joe,pierre;charlie;dog,cat`, etc).

Comment: Using the "split" method on "AB523:joe,pierre;charlie;dog,cat" wouldn't be the best solution in that case right? I can't see how this would be effective...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have control over the file format, I'd suggest tab-delimited.  Lots of other programs (e.g. Excel) will read tab delimited.  So the file would look like the following (\t represents the tab)

```
AB523\tjoe, pierre\tcharlie\tdogs,cat
ZZ883\tronald, zigomarre\tpele
```

Note - You can't use comma delimited (CSV), another common format, because comma is a legal value in your strings.  Likewise, tab delimited will have issues if the tab character is a legal character in your strings.

Like the others suggest, String.split() is a good way to parse the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the data file, generate it in a standard firmat like CSV (for simple linear data) or Json (for structured data) or even XML (for heavy processing of structured data).